# Running PHPUnit in debug mode gives 'Unable to open 'BaseTestRunner.php': File not found' error

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpunit, xdebug, homestead

I am running Homestead on Windows 10 machine with Virtual Box. I have VSCode running on the Windows machine and I want to be able to debug code in the VM.

I have followed this setup:

https://tighten.co/blog/debugging-configure-xdebug-and-laravel-homestead-and-vs-code-and-phpunit

Once I am listening for Xdebug I run my code in the VM using `phpunit test/Feature/AdminTest.php` and this fails with

> Unable to open 'BaseTestRunner.php': File not found
>   (file:///c:/g/Sites/Laravel/everyone-in-mind/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php).

Which is obviously showing me the Windows path.

If I stop the debugger and run again the test runs fine.

Do I need to install something extra to get `BaseTestRunner`?

Answer (score 0):

When you are debuging a PHPUnittest with xDebug in VSCode with the PHPUnit plugin from Elon Mallin, check that you have disable the option Breakpoints/Everything.

It seems as if PHPUnittest, running from the PHPUnit-plugin, could not find the BaseTestRunner.php file and raised an exection. When you ignore this exception, you can run and debug your test.

see the same question [PHpUnit with xdebug Breaks at BaseTestRunner instead of the actual test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58446567/phpunit-with-xdebug-breaks-at-basetestrunner-instead-of-the-actual-test)

It works for me and can now debug the Unittest.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please elaborate your answer including relevant information from the link?